# Tie a select element to a input element in ruby/haml

Tags: html, ruby, haml

Have a ruby hash `@vars`
Would like a select control to display the keys, and an input element to display the value of the selected key.

Easy enough to do the first part, but I'm at a loss on how to use the select value to index the ruby hash.

```
%select{:name=>'var', :onchange =>"document.getElementById('var_val').value=value"}
  -@vars.each do |k,v|
    %option #{k}
%input#var_val{:type => 'text', :name => 'var_val', :value => '0'}
```

This successfully sets the input field to the selected text itself, but how do I set it to essentially `@vars[select.value]`?

Comment: Why does a `<select>` act only as a proxy to an `<input>`, when a `<select>` is itself a form element that would have the same value? Seems silly.

Comment: That's just it, I want to look up the value where the select option holds the key, and display the value in the input (not the key)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's an easier way, but this seems to do the trick:

```
  %select{:id=>'var', :onchange =>"document.getElementById('var_val').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes[0].value"}
    -@vars.each do |k,v|
      %option{:name => v} #{k}
  %input#var_val{:type => 'text', :name => 'var_val', :value => @vars.first[1]}
```

Will hold out for a better answer...